# Updating a different model using radio buttons with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know this is probably very easy! I have two radio buttons that ng-show a div with an input field if the 'site' radio button has been selected. The text input field is set to a ng-model called 'sitePostcode'. What I am trying to achieve is that if the 'solution' radio button is selected then 'sitePostcode' model will have 'solution' in it. And if  the 'site' radio button is selected, then 'sitePostcode' will contain what ever was entered into the input box.

```
<div>
<input type="radio" ng-model="product.group" value="Solution">Solution
<input type="radio" ng-model="product.group" value="Site">Site
</div>

<div ng-show="product.group == 'Site'">
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter site postcode" ng-model="sitePostcode" class="form-control">
</div>
```

I thought that the radio buttons should also be 'sitePostcode' model, but when I tried that and entered text into the input field the div would dissapear as the model value changes from 'site'. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can watch changes of product.group and change sitePostcode in accordance to it.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="MainController">
        <div>
            <input type="radio" ng-model="product.group" value="Solution">Solution
            <input type="radio" ng-model="product.group" value="Site">Site
        </div>

        <div ng-show="product.group == 'Site'">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter site postcode" ng-model="sitePostcode" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <script>
            var app = angular.module('app', []);
            app.controller("MainController", function($scope) {
                var customPostcode = '';
                $scope.$watch('product.group', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                    if (newVal === 'Solution') {
                        customPostcode = $scope.sitePostcode;
                        $scope.sitePostcode = 'Solution';
                    } else {
                        $scope.sitePostcode = customPostcode;
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The radio buttons should belong to a group.  Add 'name' attribute to the input fields and give them the same value.

```
<input name="group1" type="radio" ng-model="product.group" value="Solution">Solution

<input name="group1" type="radio" ng-model="product.group" value="Site">Site
```

Radio buttons can be tricky in Angularjs.  Here is a great example of how they can work:  http://jsfiddle.net/K9MLk/246/.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best way to do this is to check the `product.group` value in the controller and set the `sitePostcode` to Solution.

Another way to do this is as you suggested. You can set the `ng-model` of your radio buttons to `sitePostcode` and change your check to `ng-show="product.group != 'Solution'"`. This is assuming that the user will not type **Solution** in the input field.

```
    <div>
<input type="radio" ng-model="sitePostcode" value="Solution">Solution
<input type="radio" ng-model="sitePostcode" value="Site">Site
</div>

<div ng-show="product.group != 'Solution'">
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter site postcode" ng-model="sitePostcode" class="form-control">
</div>
```

But as I said it is best to do this in the controller.